# copy all items from list to another using sharepoint designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

i am trying to copy all items from one list to another based on conditions, the problem is the the item will copy only once i update the item using [Current Item], is there any way to copy the item to another list without editing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [content organizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558288%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for moving documenten between libraries based on rules

The Content Organizer makes routing decisions by analyzing the metadata associated with each individual item. You can still base routing decisions on content types, but the new level of detail based on analyzing metadata enables the Content Organizer to make complex document management decisions based on rules defined by the content steward or librarian.